# Prevent a route from matching on the wrong namespace?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an API with an admin namespace that has many of the same routes as the parent namespace:

```
App::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resources :posts
    namespace :admin do
      resources :posts
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever I try to navigate to `/api/admin/posts`, I hit the controller action for `/api/posts`.

Is it possible to prevent matching the first route when I am in fact trying to hit the admin namespace?

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do -- you want the `/api/admin/posts` path to hit a different controller?

Comment: That's confusing, what you're saying is not possible. :-)

Comment: Yes, `/api/admin/posts` should hit my `api/admin/posts#index` action instead of `api/posts#index`

Comment: Have you tried moving the first `resources :posts` *after* the namespace :admin block?

Comment: Add the output of the api and post lines from `rake routes` to your question.

Comment: Do you have posts_controller and admin_controller?